# How to subclass when __init__ calls a function you want to modify

Tags: python

I have a parent class

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self, num_wheels=4):
        self.reset_horsepower(num_wheels)

    def reset_horsepower(self, num_wheels):
        self.hp = num_wheels * 20

    def upgrade_engine(self):
        self.hp *= 2
```

And I want to subclass it like this:

```
class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Car, self).__init__()

    def reset_horsepower(self):
        self.hp = 4 * 20
```

But that gives the following error:

> reset_horsepower() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

So it seems that the call to super's `__init__` is causing the old definition of `reset_horsepower` to be called

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: It calls the *new* definition of `reset_horsepower` in `Car`, if you look at the error message. You are overloading the base `reset_horsepower` with a method with non-matching signature.

Comment: the parameters in `Car` should match even if you don't need them

Comment: Ahh, so it's trying to call the new definition with an argument which is raising the error. So what's the right pattern here? (given that the parent class is also my own code)

Comment: PS sorry for the multiple edits

Comment: why are you even overriding the `reset_horsepower` method? Just use the original implementation with the right amount of wheels...

Comment: Either make the signature match exactly, or ignore any args by specifying `*args` as argument. From a Python language standpoint neither is more "correct" than the other, though the maintainability will vary. You will notice down the line. I'd prefer the former. Usually the "right" way is just by convention, OOP in Python allows a lot of possibly insane things.

Comment: I'm trying to demonstrate in a tutorial that reset_horsepower is not allowed to take any arguments. And that's related to the physical constraints of a problem, rather than python code.

Answer (score 2):

When `calculate_horsepower` is called in `Vehicle.__init__`, `self` is *still* an instance of `Car`, so `Car.calculate_horsepower` is called, not `Vehicle.calculate_horsepower`.

I would recommend changing the signatures slightly. `Vehicle.__init__` should take a *required* `num_wheels` argument; subclasses with 4 wheels can specify the value explicitly. Also, if you want to override `calculate_horsepower` but call it from the parent class, you need to preserve the function signature. I would recommend using the number of wheels in the instance, not an explicit argument.

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, num_wheels, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_wheels = num_wheels
        self.reset_horsepower()

    def calculate_horsepower(self):
        self.hp = self.num_wheels * 20

    def upgrade_engine(self):
        self.hp *= 2


class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        wheels = kwargs.get('num_wheels', 4)
        super().__init__(wheels, **kwargs)


c = Car()
```

`Car` doesn't need to implement `reset_horsepower`, assuming that `4` in its definition is supposed to refer to the expected number of wheels on a car.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I learned from writing inheritance / polymorphism code is that you should never call methods that are overridden by subclasses **during construction**. It should be noted that during object construction, as the name implies, means that the object is only being created currently and would only be fully constructed once the whole `__init__` is done. Thus on your code, at the time `super().__init__` is called, the subclass implementation isn't actually setup yet.

Some reading material I came across now was this:

- [https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/PYTHON/**init**+method+calls+overridden+method](https://help.semmle.com/wiki/display/PYTHON/__init__+method+calls+overridden+method)

Quoting:

> Recommendation
>
> Do not use methods that are subclassed in the
>   construction of an object. For simpler cases move the initialization
>   into the superclass' **init** method, preventing it being overridden.
>   Additional initialization of subclass should be done in the **init**
>   method of the subclass. For more complex cases, it is advisable to use
>   a static method or function to manage object creation.

Based on that article, a proposed solution is:

```
class Vehicle():
    def __init__(self, num_wheels=4):
        self.super_reset_horsepower(num_wheels)

    def super_reset_horsepower(self, num_wheels):
        self.hp = num_wheels * 20

class Car(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Car, self).__init__()
        self.sub_reset_horsepower()

    def sub_reset_horsepower(self):
        self.hp = 4 * 20
```